Dynamics 365 navigation item
I am trying to add a link on the left hand side navigation that opens a specific record.
The following code works, however it opens the whole application in the window (with a second navigation etc.) rather than just the record.
I have included the commented out line which works to open the record in a new tab, but I would rather stay in the main application.
The link to this HTML file is placed in the navigation to a webresource.
Can anyone help with code modifications please?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ensureXrmLoaded(callback) {
            if (typeof window.top.Xrm !== 'undefined' && window.top.Xrm.Utility) {
                callback();
            } else {
                console.log('Xrm is not loaded yet, retrying...');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    ensureXrmLoaded(callback);
                }, 500);  // Increased delay to 500ms
            }
        }

        async function getCurrentUserId() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(window.top.Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + '/api/data/v9.1/WhoAmI', {
                    headers: {
                        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                        'OData-Version': '4.0',
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    console.log('User ID:', data.UserId);
                    return data.UserId;
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Error retrieving current user ID: ' + response.statusText);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            }
        }

        async function getRecordIdForCurrentUser(userId) {
            try {
                const query = `/api/data/v9.1/new_tutorstrainersandmentors?$filter=_new_systemuser_value eq ${userId}`;
                const response = await fetch(window.top.Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + query, {
                    headers: {
                        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                        'OData-Version': '4.0',
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    if (data.value.length > 0) {
                        console.log('Record ID:', data.value[0].new_tutorstrainersandmentorid);
                        return data.value[0].new_tutorstrainersandmentorid;
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('No matching records found.');
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Error retrieving related record: ' + response.statusText);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            }
        }

        async function openCustomForm() {
            try {
                const userId = await getCurrentUserId();
                const recordId = await getRecordIdForCurrentUser(userId);
                const formId = '769d1133-1a2c-ef11-840a-000d3a655ff1'; // Replace with the actual form ID
                const formUrl = `/main.aspx?appid=fd466ced-1d9f-ea11-a812-000d3ab29ddd&pagetype=entityrecord&etn=new_tutorstrainersandmentor&id=${recordId}&formid=${formId}&forceUCI=1`;

                // Open the form in the current tab
                window.location.href = formUrl;
                //window.open(formUrl, '_blank');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error opening custom form:', error);
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
            ensureXrmLoaded(openCustomForm);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>


Changing the openCustomForm function fixed the problem.
async function openCustomForm(Xrm) {
    try {
        const userId = await getCurrentUserId(Xrm);
        const recordId = await getRecordIdForCurrentUser(Xrm, userId);
        const formId = '769d1133-1a2c-ef11-840a-000d3a655ff1'; // Replace with the actual form ID

        // Constructing the entity form options
        const entityFormOptions = {
            pageType: 'entityrecord',
            entityName: 'new_tutorstrainersandmentor',
            entityId: recordId,
            formId: formId
        };

        // Navigate to the entity form
        console.log(entityFormOptions)
        Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(entityFormOptions);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error opening custom form:', error);
    }
}

